# Asterisk Call Transfer to Playback then resume back call

Tags: asterisk

Here is my scenario i want to achieve, I have do outbound call to a number, after conversation i need to transfer the call to play a message for callee. After the message end, the call will route back to caller continue conversation.

How am i going to achieve this. using method MeetMe? or others?

Comment: after conversation: apply `UserTransfer` to any `extensions` and on that extensions you can play and route back to callee

Comment: Do you mind to share the dialplan?

Answer (score 1):

Dialplan should be something like this:

```
[default]
exten => _10XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

After the conversation if the user transfer the call to "Music" extensions: (from sip client i guess):

```
[Music]
exten => _X.,n,Playback(your_play_file)
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```

better if you can manipulate using `AGI` to get/set the user was talking to the caller.

alternate:

you can use [Call Parking](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+call+parking) for this.